# Connect to database in Google Drive

Tags: php, mysql, sql, google-drive-api

In my Google Drive Storrage I have a database (SQL file) which I want to read out from a PHP file on my webserver. The database looks like this:

```
DB_Name:  Test
TBL_Name: Namen

| id | Vorname |  Nachname  |
-----------------------------
|  1 | Max     | Mustermann |
|  2 | Hanz    | Peter      |
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Now I tried to connect to the SQL file with this basic PHP code:

```
$verbindung = mysql_connect($driveLink, "", "")
or die("Failed to create connection.");

mysql_select_db("Test")
or die ("The database does not exists.");

$abfrage = "SELECT Vorname FROM Namen";
$ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage);

while($row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis))
{
    echo "$row->Vorname";
}
```

But I can't get a connection to the file. Why is that? I have not set a username or password for the database so I pass empty strings to it, right? Also I gave the file access to everyone so I can reach the file from my code.

Is that because there is no underlying system like PhpMyAdmin or something else? How can I connect to the database from PHP?

Comment: You could perhaps use sqlite in your google drive storage - and use the sqlite functions of PHP. But to use a MySQL server you need a MySQL server up and running to connect to. That's a bit more than having just one file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An SQL file only contains raw SQL commands, which you can run on a database server.

When you use `mysql_connect`, you have to connect to a database server (specifically a MySQL database server). Then you can use other SQL commands via `mysql_query`.

> Is that because there is no underlying system

Yes

> like PhpMyAdmin

No. PHPMyAdmin is an SQL **client**, not a server. It also has to connect to a MySQL server.

---

NB: `mysql_` is [an **obsolete** database API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: Okay thank you for that. So may it is possible to me to parse throught the sql file and read out the data without a connection?

Comment: Possible, but probably not easy or efficient.

Answer (score 0):

this is inpossible
because php cannot 'read' the sql-File
so you have to make a online Databse

there are some free services for that:

[my hostpoint](http://www.hostpoint.ch/)